# how to execute INSERT statement using PgAgent Job scheduler in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, job-scheduling, pgagent

I have his query

```
INSERT INTO public.mb51_helper(
    plant)
    VALUES ('1826')
;
```

Every hour. I have setup all everything. PgAgent Service is running in services but it is not executing the query.

Comment: I want to execute this query every minute.

Comment: quick question: does the pgAgent user have access to this database? Can you show what the log says? <-- in pgAdmin in the `output` column ;-)

Comment: Yes I have the access to the column.

Comment: Can you also post the error message? Does the job can be started manually?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of PgAgent in registry. I went to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CURRENT_CONTROL_SET?SERVICES/pgAgent

Change the image path.
To the folder path of the PgAgent is present
"C:/Program Files/PostgresSQL/12/bin/pgagent.exe" RUN pgAgent -u WINDOWS_USER -p WINDOWS_PASSWORD hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres

And the the OBJECT NAME To
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE

You can change this in going to services or directly by changing the name of the object.